# finding pi - using Machin's formula. Different iterations are giving same result

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pi

I've written a few programs to find pi, this one being the most advanced. I used Machin's formula, `pi/4 = 4(arc-tan(1/5)) - (arc-tan(1/239))`.

The problem is that however many iterations I do, I get the same result, and I can't seem to understand why.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

double arctan_series(int x, double y) // x is the # of iterations while y     is the number
{
    double pi = y;
    double temp_Pi;
    for (int i = 1, j = 3; i < x; i++, j += 2) 
    {
        temp_Pi = pow(y, j) / j; //the actual value of the iteration
        if (i % 2 != 0)     // for every odd iteration that subtracts
        {
            pi -= temp_Pi;
        }
        else    // for every even iteration that adds
        {
            pi += temp_Pi;
        }
    }
    pi = pi * 4;
    return pi;
}

double calculations(int x) // x is the # of iterations
{
    double value_1, value_2, answer;
    value_1 = arctan_series(x, 0.2);
    value_2 = arctan_series(x, 1.0 / 239.0);
    answer = (4 * value_1) - (value_2);
    return answer;
}

int main() 
{
    double pi;
    int iteration_num;
    cout << "Enter the number of iterations: ";
    cin >> iteration_num;
    pi = calculations(iteration_num);
    cout << "Pi has the value of: " << setprecision(100) << fixed << pi     << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to reproduce your issue, but here is a bit cleaned up code with a few C++11 idioms and better variable names.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

// double arctan_series(int x, double y) // x is the # of iterations while y     is the number
// then why not name the parameters accoringly? In math we usually use x for the parameter.
// prefer C++11 and the auto notation wherever possible
auto arctan_series(int iterations, double x) -> double
{
    // note, that we don't need any temporaries here.

    // note, that this loop will never run, when iterations = 1
    // is that really what was intended?
    for (int i = 1, j = 3; i < iterations; i++, j += 2) 
    {
        // declare variables as late as possible and always initialize them
        auto t = pow(x, j) / j;
        // in such simple cases I prefer ?: over if-else. Your milage may vary
        x += (i % 2 != 0) ? -t : t;
    }
    return x * 4;
}

// double calculations(int x) // x is the # of iterations
// then why not name the parameter accordingly
// BTW rename the function to what it is supposed to do
auto approximate_pi(int iterations) -> double
{
    // we don't need all of these temporaries. Just write one expression.
    return 4 * arctan_series(iterations, 0.2) - arctan_series(iterations, 1.0 / 239.0);
}

auto main(int, char**) -> int
{
    cout << "Enter the number of iterations: ";
    // in C++ you should declare variables as late as possible
    // and always initialize them.
    int iteration_num = 0;
    cin >> iteration_num;

    cout << "Pi has the value of: "
         << setprecision(100) << fixed
         << approximate_pi(iteration_num) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When you remove my explanatory comments, you'll see, that the resulting code is a lot more concise, easier to read, and therefore easier to maintain.

I tried a bit:

```
Enter the number of iterations: 3
Pi has the value of: 3.1416210293250346197169164952356368303298950195312500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Enter the number of iterations: 2
Pi has the value of: 3.1405970293260603298790556436870247125625610351562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Enter the number of iterations: 7
Pi has the value of: 3.1415926536235549981768144789384678006172180175781250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Enter the number of iterations: 42
Pi has the value of: 3.1415926535897940041763831686694175004959106445312500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

As you see, I obviously get different results for different numbers of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

That method converges very quickly. You'll get more accuracy if you start with the smallest numbers first. Since 5^23 > 2^53 (the number of bits in the mantissa of a double), probably the maximum number of iterations is 12 (13 won't make any difference). You'll get more accuracy starting with the smaller numbers. The changed lines have comments:

```
double arctan_series(int x, double y)
{
    double pi = y;
    double temp_Pi;
    for (int i = 1, j = x*2-1; i < x; i++, j -= 2) // changed this line
    {
        temp_Pi = pow(y, j) / j;
        if ((j & 2) != 0)    // changed this line
        {
            pi -= temp_Pi;
        }
        else
        {
            pi += temp_Pi;
        }
    }
    pi = pi * 4;
    return pi;
}
```

For doubles, there is no point in setting precision > 18.

If you want an alternative formula that takes more iterations to converge, use pi/4 = arc-tan(1/2) + arc-tan(1/3), which will take about 24 iterations.

Comment: sorry, what does & do? I only know of &&. And does that mean i can't get more decimal values regardless of how many iterations?

Comment: @IllorenzoAn - & is [bitwise and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). With 64 bit doubles, 12 iterations with your formula is all the accuracy you can get. You'd have to use some type of extended math (arrays) to get more digits.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. Are there any individual libraries i can use? Or should i use arrays?

Comment: I know of two big number libraries, but have't used either. [gnu gmp](http://gmplib.org) and [apfloat](http://apfloat.org/apfloat) .

Answer (score 0):

This is another way if some of you are interested. The loop calculates the integral of the function : **sqrt(1-x²)**

Which represents a semicircle of radius 1. Then we multiply by two the area. Finally we got the surface of the circle which is PI.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

#define f(x) sqrt(1-pow(x,2))

double integral(int a, int b, int p)
{
    double d=pow(10, -p), s=0;
    for (double x=a ; x+d<=b ; x+=d)
    {
        s+=f(x)+f(x+d);
    }
    s*=d/2.0;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "PI=" << setprecision (9) << 2.0*integral(-1,1,6) << endl;
}
```